# JavaScript Word Generator

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a word generator. You enter in ten strings of your choice. It should output one string that it randomly selected. It outputs a randomly selected number instead and it shouldn't. It should output a string entered by the user. I don't get errors.

How do I get this to display the user input?

Any suggestions? I've been stuck on this the last few days.

```
function randomWordGenerator() {

  // Define the variables
  var userInput = [];
  var answer = [], range = 1;
  var array = [];
  var set = [];

  // Prompt for String
  for(var index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    userInput = prompt("Please enter string." + (index + 1));
    document.write("You entered: " + userInput + "\n");
  }

  // Generator
  for(var i = 0; i < range; i++) {
    answer[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  }

  // Generator Pick Display
  document.write("The generator choose: " + answer);
}

randomWordGenerator();
```

Comment: What is your question?  What problem are you having?  `everything I want displays properly.` okay, then what's the issue?

Comment: How do I get this to display a entered string and not the number picked by the math.random function?

Comment: You overwrite `userInput` on each loop and you never use it after that. Perhaps you should keep each input?

Comment: Why prompt in a loop. I don't get it.

Comment: To avoid confusion with future readers, I'm removing the phrase "everything I want displays properly" since it isn't actually displaying everything you want.  I'm not sure what you meant by that phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save the user input into the array. What you are doing in your code is overwriting `userInput` all the time, i.e. only the last word the user entered is save in that variable. And then you generate some random numbers, push them all into an array and output that to the user. Here is how it would work:

```js
function randomWordGenerator() {

  // Define the variables
  var array = [];

  // Prompt for String
  for (var index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    var userInput = prompt("Please enter string." + (index + 1));
    array.push(userInput);
    document.write("You entered: " + userInput + "\n");
  }

  // select random number from array in which you stored the words
  var answer = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];

  // Generator Pick Display
  document.write("The generator choose: " + answer);
}

randomWordGenerator();
```